# How to permanently bend bamboo?

Tags: technique-identification, woodworking

I notice that rakes made out of bamboo have curved tines (as shown below).

[image]

How can I permanently bend bamboo like there tines?

Answer (score 5):

In most commercial applications, the bamboo is treated with steam to soften it.  You can also soften it by soaking in water, but it takes a lot longer.  You can even apply heat to the bamboo, which softens it and turns the water contained in the bamboo to steam.

If a specific shape needs to be replicated, like those tines, the softened bamboo is put in a form until it cools and dries out.  Steam treatment followed by a form is essentially the same as the process for bending wood.

[3 Ways to Bend Bamboo](https://www.wikihow.com/Bend-Bamboo), describes three ways that don't require a steam chamber.

Comment: Wet bending (of wood) can also be done by applying a little tension, soaking repeatedly, and increasing the tension in small steps over several days.  That's more useful for big pieces you can't fit in a tub but could be used on small stuff too, especially if you want to make one former that will hold several pieces.  Hot water soaking will speed things up a bit compared to cold